# How to display java String with html tag appended, with the html behavior in angualrjs front end

Tags: java, angularjs, html

I have  a string in java,I need to append html tag to it dynamically so that when displayed in the frond it,the html tags behavior is felt.
Eg:

```
String content="Hello World,this is a test <em>content</em> to demonstrate the requirement";
```

In the above string content is wrapped inside the `<em>` tag.But when I am trying to display it in angularjs front end, the string is not taking the tag behavior and displayed as "Hello World,this is a test <em>content</em> to demonstrate the requirement".

Comment: can you please detail us which tag you want?

Comment: String content="Hello World,this is a test <em>content<em> to demonstrate the requirement";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use angular-sanitize.js for the same - 
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/frrLhx57/)

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <div ng-bind-html="stringTest"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-bind-html`

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <div ng-bind-html="stringTest"></div>
</div>
```

However, if you find this directive too restrictive and when you absolutely trust the source of the content you are binding to, then you can also use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="stringTest"></div>
</div>
```